# Which Ubuntu release should I use for an old Vista computer?

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit

I am new to linux.  I have installed the 14.04.1 i386 on an old computer (Intel Pentium due core E2180, 32bit, 2GHz, 2GB RAM).  Install itself was smooth, but only some apps are working.  Many will cause the computer to hang.  Maybe, I should be using an older Ubuntu release to match up with the computer?  If yes, which one, the 10. or the 12. ? Appreciate any ideas and advice. -KL

Comment: This question possibly already has an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/164093

Answer (score 1):

It is **not advised** to install an older version of Ubuntu unless it is still supported (like 12.04).

For a machine with low system specs, it is better to install an up to date but lightweight flavour of Ubuntu like [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).